# Not able to kill running application

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions

I have tried to kill the running applications using following code but it is not working please give any suggestion.
Using `restartPackage()`, `KillingBackgroundProcess()`, `android.os.processes.killprocess(pid)` but nothing is working.Is it not supported by android or android kernel not giving us that much permission to kill the other applications.

```
Intent ints = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
ints.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

checkedapp = name.get(position);

Log.w("Checked app name", checkedapp);

PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

List<ResolveInfo> intentlist = pm.queryIntentActivities(ints,
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

ActivityManager am1 = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

List<RunningTaskInfo> processes = am1.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

if (processes != null) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < processes.size(); i++) 
  {
    String packageName = processes.get(i).topActivity.getPackageName();

    Log.w("packagename", packageName);
    RunningTaskInfo temp = processes.get(i);

    try 
    {
      pName = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName,
                                        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
    } 
     catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
    {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (checkedapp.equals(pName)) 
    {

      am1.killBackgroundProcesses(packageName);

      //String pid = Integer.toString(temp.id);

        int pid=temp.id;

    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);    

//Log.w("processid", pid);

icons.remove(position);
name.remove(position);

} 

Is it really not possible to force stop any running application in android programmatically.
Please help.
```

Comment: Did you add the permission in the Manifest file ? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RESTART_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />

Comment: yes.I have added these permissions in my androidmanifest.xml

Comment: This is not something you are supposed to be able to do; that it may be possible on some older versions of Android is basically a design bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to kill another application's process from yours, From ICS this restriction implies. the code you written may work on earlier versions still i never tried on them.

Comment: I am using this code on 2.3 Gingerbread but it still not working.